# Vistas en Laravel no reflejan los cambios

Tags: html, laravel, cache, views

Lo que pasa es que estaba trabajando en un computador diferente pero al trasladar mi proyecto a otro computador hay una parte del código relacionado a las ventanas modales que no funciona, lo que sucede es que cuando hago una petición ajax y si esta arroja algún error la ventana modal se abriría nuevamente pero no sucede.

Ya he usado los comandos para borrar el cache

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

He borrado manualmente las carpetas que almacenan el cache en storage.

Lo curioso es que si sigo trabajando en el nuevo computador no funciona esa parte relacionada a las modales pero si guardo y envió al otro computador si funciona todo normal.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser algo del cache, intentaste en incognito ? Si modificaste CSS Y JS prueba modificando las versiones de los archivos estáticos linkeadas en el HEAD, también podrías intentar desde otro navegador, donde nunca hayas abierto el proyecto. (Me ha pasado que hasta en incognito se me cachea) Si estas con Apache o NGINX prueba ver la configuración de cache de éstos, además del cache de tu navegador.

Por último el php artisan optimize es el que mejor limpia, todo puedes intentar borrar las vistas y rutas desde el cache/bootstrap (ojo no borrar la carpeta cache/bootstrap) ya que lo que hiciste fue borrar las vistas desde el storage.

También puedes intentar debugear e ir matando el proceso, es decir meterte a la vista que da errores y meter en el .blade.php una etiqueta @php dd('entró a la vista'); @endphp

Saludos.